# Eclipse > git - what is Assume Valid?

Tags: eclipse

Looking through Eclipse's Label Decorations for Git, I see one with a tick that says `assume-valid.txt`.

What is `Assume Valid`?

Answer (score 0):

***assume-valid*** - The resource has the "assume unchanged" flag. This means that Git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell Git when you change the working tree file. This setting can be switched on with the menu action Team->Assume unchanged (or on the command line with git update-index --assume-unchanged).

Check out more at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State